# Remove unnecessary y-axis points with facet_wrap and geom_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm mapping y-axis points to the x-axis using `geom_segment()` and then using `facet_wrap` to separate data into two plots; however, the y-axis points are showing up on both plots.

How can I have only the necessary y-axis points pertaining to each `facet_wrap`?

**Sample Code**

```
dat <- structure(list(temp = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), rev = c(-5, 
-11, -20, -29, -40, -9, -20, -32, -45, -57, -12, -24, -37, -50, 
-62, -7, -20, -36, -52, -67, -5, -13, -23, -35, -47, -12, -24, 
-36, -48, -58), type = c("Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2"), model = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C")), .Names = c("temp", "rev", "type", "model"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(temp, rev, color = model)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = temp, yend = rev), linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") + 
  facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = dat$rev)
p1
```

**Plot**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made up dummy data because for some reason pasting your `dput` into my console made it unhappy.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- expand.grid(temp = 1:5, model = LETTERS[1:3], type = 1:2) %>% 
  group_by(model, type) %>% 
  mutate(rev = -sort(sample.int(20, length(temp)))) 

# this is equivalent to your data as-is, structurewise
```

---

```
df.labeled <- df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% group_by(type, rev) %>% 
  mutate(label = c(rev[1], rep(NA, length(rev) - 1)))
```

Here I created a group for each y value that shows up in each group panel. Then I create a `label` column which consists of 1 observation of that y value, padded with `NA`s. So if a panel would have had two models that each had a `rev` of `-5`, now it would be `-5, NA` instead of `-5, -5`. Why I'm doing this will become clearer below.

---

```
ggplot(df.labeled, aes(temp, rev, color = model)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = 0, yend = rev), linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, x = -0.1), colour = "black", hjust = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_grid(~type) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, NA)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

If I had left in the duplicates (here would have been -7, -15 for type 1 and -11 for type 2), the `geom_text` would have been a messy bolded blur. Duplicated text labels don't render well in `ggplot2`. Since it's not really possible to do it the way you wanted, here we're just making a fake scale for each panel. If you don't like the fact that there's an extra line on the y-axis to the left of the numbers, that can be gotten rid of:

```
  ... + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: This works great, unless I add more models. Then I get bunching on the y-axis labels, thus making them hard to read. Is there a way to use this method, but spread out the y-axis to prevent overlapping labels?

Comment: If there's that many points, perhaps a regular unmodified y-axis is best ;) You can always try using a taller aspect ratio: `ggsave("file.png", width = 6, height = 8)`. You could also try the `ggrepel` package to nudge the labels around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

We can split the data frame by the `type`, create separated plot, and then use `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package to combine two plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Split the data
dat_list <- split(dat, dat$type)

# Use lapply to create plot for both subset
p_list <- lapply(dat_list, function(x){

  p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(temp, rev, color = model)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = temp, yend = rev), linetype = "dashed", color = "grey") + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = x$rev) +
    facet_wrap(~type, scales = "free")
  return(p1)
})

# Plot the data
grid.arrange(grobs = p_list, nrow = 1)
```

#### Update

Another option is to use the `cowplot` package. This seems to be a way to create a common legend.

```
library(cowplot)

# Get the common legend, p_list is from the previous example
legend_both <- get_legend(p_list[[1]])

# Plot the plots and the common legend together
# Use rel_widths to set the column width
plot_grid(p_list[[1]] + theme(legend.position = "none"),
          p_list[[2]] + theme(legend.position = "none"),
          legend_both, 
          nrow = 1,
          rel_widths = c(2, 2, 1))
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but I was hoping for a way to keep it in `ggplot` without having to split the data.  This way the y-axis would line up to show relationships across models and types. Thanks though.

Comment: I know. It would be great to use `ggplot2` only. I am still searching for possible ways to do it. Hopefully, others can share their ideas.

Comment: To keep the axes aligned, you can use a combination of `cbind.gtable` and `grid.arrange`, but there's a hack workaround as well...

Comment: I generally use `cowplot` for multiplot, so this is certainly an option too. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is WAY later and maybe package changed since 2017, but for those who are looking to keep the y axis consistent across facets use 'scales = "free_x". No need to force a common y axis outside of ggplot2